# Problem about pointwise and uniformly convergence

Tags: real-analysis

We define $f_n$ define the functions with $n \in N$, as follows:

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
\sin(x) &\mbox{if } 2\pi n \leq x  \leq 2\pi(n+1) \\
0 & \mbox{if other way} \end{cases} 
$$
The functions $f_n$ are uniformly bounded and equicontinuous and converge
pointwise, but not uniformly, to $0$.

I try dividing the inequalities between $ n $ but is not useful, please help me.

Comment: Try to see what is $||f_n(x)|| = sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{|f_n(x)|\}$. Hint, it does not depend on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that $f_n(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $n,x$, hence they are uniformly bounded.

$f_n$ is Lipschitz continuous with rank $1$ for all $n$, hence equicontinuous.

Finally, $f_n(2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$ for all $n$. Hence the $f_n$ cannot converge to $0$ uniformly;.